# Azure GPU instances?

Tags: azure, cloud

I see various blog posts and press releases saying Azure has GPU instances (N-type), but I can't see them anywhere. Are they a private beta? (How do I sign up?)  Are they only in a specific region?

Comment: I give you my plus. I don't understand why this question has -3 votes without explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The N series are still in beta. There was an announcement at AzureCon and Build 2016:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/videos/azurecon-2015-applications-that-scale-using-gpu-compute/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/videos/build-2016-introduction-to-nvidia-gpus-in-azure/